# Is there a way to add Couchbase indexes to version control?

Tags: indexing, version-control, couchbase

When dealing with MSSQL, there are loads of options for how to add the schema (including indexes) into version control (database projects, Redgate SQL Source Control, etc.), but we're looking to introduce Couchbase into our application, and I'm looking for a way to add indexes into version control (currently using Git with TFS).

We've got multiple environments (test, staging, live, etc.), and we're going to want to make sure we deploy the same index changes to each Couchbase cluster set up for each environment.

How do we ensure that we can bundle Couchbase index alongside a specific release, or does this need to be a manual job?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming we're talking about N1QL indexes, you can create them using N1QL syntax as documented here: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/createindex.html

So you could do this programmatically, either using the query support in the SDKs or the REST interface directly.

In addition, we have SDK wrappers around these.  There are some hints on how to use them with Java SDK 2.x here: https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/n1ql-query.html#index-building, but we are aiming for more complete documentation in this area for 3.x.  I will update once they're available.